# Installing PyAudio

Tags: python, windows

I'm having an error installing the PyAudio library on VSC, PyCharm and CMD on windows. I already installed the pip, anaconda, weel.

````
  Using cached PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz (37 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: PyAudio
  Building wheel for PyAudio (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\mylen\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-mrc1mi4g\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\mylen\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-mrc1mi4g\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\mylen\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-l93ob1lx'
       cwd: C:\Users\mylen\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mrc1mi4g\pyaudio\
  Complete output (15 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8
  copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8
  running build_ext
  building '_portaudio' extension
  creating build\temp.win32-3.8
  creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release
  creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\src
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD "-Ic:\program files (x86)\python38-32\include" "-Ic:\program files (x86)\python38-32\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.8\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
  _portaudiomodule.c
  src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: NÆo ‚ poss¡vel abrir arquivo incluir: 'portaudio.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.27.29110\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for PyAudio```
````

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not in English

Comment: Please post in English, or to post in Portuguese, use [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com)